# Print all the squares from natural numbers

Tags: java

Given this problem:

Read an integer number N from the input and print all the squares of natural numbers:

- less than or equal to N,
- in ascending order.

I can't quite get the grasp of the problem. Could somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = entrada.nextInt();
        
        double raiz = Math.sqrt(n);

        do {
            if (n % (raiz * raiz) == 0) {
                System.out.println(Math.pow(n,n));
            }
        } while (n <= Math.sqrt(n));
        
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks like a lot of unnecessary things. All you need is a single while loop.

Comment: First of all, you don't proceed while loop, there might be an infinite loop.

Comment: @aydinugur It's pretty obvious that he wants numbers from 1 to n.

Comment: Gotta do the exercise with a while loop. It's my first month of uni as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to build the squares until you exceed the value N. Try:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = entrada.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i * i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.println(i * i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have to do this with a while loop.

Comment: Then simply change the for loop to a while loop, you should be able to do this yourself

Comment: @fatlafel In that case, I believe my answer answers the question.